# Define global environment variables from inside a stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have env vars defined in my environment directive at the top of the pipeline:

```
environment {
    var1 = 'sdfsdfdsf'
    var2 = 'sssssss'
}
```

But there are some that I need to dynamically set or override in the stages. But if I use an environment{} directive in a stage the vars won't be accessible to other stages. Initially I thought I could define them all with default values in the top environment directive and overwrite them in the pipeline but this is the behavior I observed:

1. Define var in environment block
2. Try to overwrite in script{} block like: `script {env.var1 = 'new value'}`
3. The env is not overwritten

How can I change the envs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it as follow:

1. Define var in stage environment { env.var1 = 'value' }
2. you can access same var in other stages and change value in environment { env.var1 = 'value2' }

   ```
    pipeline {
     agent any
     environment { 
        var1 = 'value'
     }

     stages {
        stage('Initialize') {
          steps {
           script {
           echo ("value : " + env.var1)
            }
          }
       }

       stage('build') {
         environment { 
           var1 = 'value2'
          }
          steps {
           script {
             echo ("value : " + env.var1)
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: but your just using script{} instead of environment{}. Why are environment{} vars not overwritable in script{}?

Comment: environment variables cannot be changed from within script{}.You can change them from within environment{} only.

Comment: right so my question is how do I set the environment var in a stage globally? In you example if i had another stage after "build" and did "echo env.var1" the value would be "value" not "value2"

Comment: i see. so the correction solution for you will be to use global variables and not environment variables. Because environment variables are not mutable.